# Network profile type (public/private) missing from GUI settings in Windows 11

Tags: networking, network-adapter, windows-11

I have two network interfaces installed on a Win 11 laptop. One for WLAN (onboard) and one for LAN (USB/dockingstation):

- The WLAN is connected to the AP/router and works fine, I can change the public/private setting the normal way over the GUI settings:

  [image]
- The LAN port is connected to a switch (with one other Win10 PC). It's show as `unidentified network` and there is no option to change it from public to private in the GUI settings:

  [image]

As a workaround I changed the LAN network profile via Powershell using `Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet 7" -NetworkCategory Private`,  <s>but why is the GUI option gone</s> (see addition 01)  and how do I get it back?

**Addition 01:** Upon further examination this seems to be [connected to The Network Location Awareness (NLA)](https://serverfault.com/questions/39767/what-settings-does-windows-use-to-determine-network-location). I suspect the option will reappear as soon as Windows is capable of identifying the network. I haven't at the time to find a way to fix this problem (except for my workaround using PowerShell). So the current question is: how can I make the local network identifiable for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NLA uses the MAC address of the user's DSL or cable modem as the link
> ID.

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa480195(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

To get the public/private option to show in the GUI windows needs to identify the network via the NLA service. To achieve that the network adapter connected to the network needs to have a default gateway.

Windows's NLA service will then identify the network by the MAC address of the device entered as default gateway. It doesn't have to be a a router, but there must be a device/MAC under that IP otherwise windows will keep trying to identify the network.

Comment: Reminds me of the old joke with the guy in a hot air balloon asking for directions.

Answer (score 1):

> Network profile type (public/private) missing from settings in Windows
> 11  .......    The LAN port is connected to a switch (with one other
> Win10 PC).

I see this on one of my Laptops - same thing. I think this is because the LAN connection does not have active Internet, so there is no need for the setting (Private / Public).

I have a Desktop Windows 11 machine with just Wired Ethernet and the Private / Public setting shows up fine.

The setting is (in effect) context sensitive as to whether needed or not. So what you see is quite normal.

Comment: Ah, good to know this is common, thx. I just tested it, internet connectivity does not seem to have anything to do with it, see the update to my question at the very end. (the private/public setting still affects firewall rules etc which come into play even without Internet access for example for RDP, that's why I want to fix this). And the setting is definitely set on the LAN connection, it makes a difference if I set it to public or private via PowerShell.

Comment: Probably Microsoft no longer considers "public" Ethernet connection "common".

Comment: Without using special methods , the outputs are what Microsoft now shows. If only a local internal connection, it does not show public / private. Tested here a lot on different computers. You can enable Network Discovery and that will normally let RDP work.

Comment: As far as I understand it's not the lack of Internet but the lack of identification that causes for lack of the auction to select private or public in the GUI (see addition01 in my question). So the question becomes: how do I make it identifiable (as far as I understand this well make the GUI option reappear)?

Comment: 'how do I make it identifiable` - Your machine will have no internet if it's unable to contact a specific Microsoft address.  I forget if it has to be just reachable or if it actually has to receive data. Why do you care if the internet is consider to be Public or Private the settings can be adjusted regardless.

Comment: @Ramhound as far as my tests go internet connectivity doesn't have anything to do with it (see my first comment and the first addition to my question). not sure if that answered your question, if not please let me know.

Comment: There are far too many comments to keep up with whatever was said.  I was just sharing knowledge anyways.  The icon indicating there is no internet, {network icon with a red cross through it", will be displayed when a Microsoft domain cannot be reached.

Comment: how do I make it identifiable (as far as I understand this well make the GUI option reappear)?   ....   Based on your question and how you are using the 2 NICs , the original GUI for Windows 11 is as you see it.

Comment: Also a Wired Connection does not need to be Public or Private. It IS private. Just turn on Network Discovery if needed.

Comment: @John the wired connection was public at first, but I managed to change it to private via CLI (see workaround described in the question). Not sure what you mean by: "the original GUI for Windows 11 is as you see it"? Currently I'm trying to figure out, how I can get NLA to identify the network, I suspect the option to reappear in the GUI once it's done.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for clarifying

Comment: I have found a solution (see my answer). +1 for your feedback, thanks a lot it's really appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  Interesting.

Comment: Public/Private does matter if you ask me, it determines which firewall rules are applied. You don't want to enable some things on all public networks just because you need access from a local lab network that Windows doesn't see as private. Good that there's still the PowerShell way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody landing here and has a hyper-v virtual switch enabled, you have to remove the vSwitch to see the network profile options. Once vSwitch is created, the options are not visible anymore.

The network profile option selected remains intact even after creating vSwitch.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with a Hyper-V virtual switch itself,  the solution is to add a default gateway [see my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1721228/201818). Alternatively, you can change the network profile type via PowerShell as I described in my question. You don't need to remove the vSwitch!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I moved my computer to another room where it connected to the WiFi repeater instead of the router. On the list of network adapters the WiFi adapter said `Unidentified network`.

The solution was to disable and then enable the network adapter.

I suppose because the repeater had a different MAC address than the router but broadcasted the same SSID the OS went in "someone is spoofing your WiFi network" mode. Once this was a network I had already connected to, it was fine?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the powershell commands below to get and set the status.

If you have a hyper-v virtual switch enabled then this is the only way I've been able to make the change.

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile 

Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Public
```

Comment: That's **precisely** the workaround I already described in my question. And the problem has nothing to do with a Hyper-V virtual switch itself. Also, it doesn't make the GUI options reappear, the solution is to add a default gateway [see my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1721228/201818)